# Why fields in structs defined by the Unix API have prefixes?

Tags: api

Many fields in structs defined by the Unix API have prefixes, like `sa_` in `sa_handler` defined in `struct sigaction`. Why is it so? Why isn't `sa_handler` called just `handler`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace

Comment: @StephenRauch, thanks for the pointer, but I don't think it answers my question. In the example for the C language, structs are used as a way to create a namespace for fields with the same name. The Unix API seems to go further and use a prefix for fields in structs, even if those fields are already namespaced by the structs themselves. I would like to understand the design decision behind this approach.

Comment: [Why are the fields in \`struct stat\` named st\_something?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10325870) as linked by @sourcejedi in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This goes back a long way, all the way to the first C versions. They didn't have a seperate symbol table for structure members, the names were added to the global symbol table. With the obvious nasty global namespace pollution that causes. The workaround was the same one you use on enums today, prefix them with a couple of letters to avoid the name collisions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325945/799204

Comment: And see also the other answers at that SO Q&A. Like the fact that making it `handler` could cause collisions when things do `#define handler something`.

Comment: Another reason for having prefixes is for applying `#define` tricks like in `#define sigev_notify_function _sigev_un._sigev_thread._function`, aliasing a member of a union and making it look like a field on the outer structure.